# Node.js Express resultset from async function not available as function value

Tags: sql, node.js, express

In a Node Express app alternative products are connected to products by product Id. The alternative products (in a separate table) are right joined to the Products on ProductAlternatives.AlternativeProductId=Products.Id. I am trying to generate a nested JSON structure where alternative products (if available) are shown in a separate array.

What I get as a result is a flat JSON structure like this:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "ProductName": "2 Zits My Style",
    "Description": "2 zits | stof | Stof grof geweven lichtgrijs",
    "Price": "579.00",
    "Picture": "~/UserImages/8195299-254-02.jpg",
    "CatID": 5,
    "alternateproducts": {}
  },
  {
    "Id": 4,
    "ProductName": "Slaapbank Hervik",
    "Description": "Cubos 50 lever",
    "Price": "1.499.00",
    "Picture": "~/UserImages/8202978-06.jpg",
    "CatID": 11,
    "alternateproducts": {}
  },
```

so, without the alternative products. The attribute alternateproducts for the first product should contain exactly 2 alternative products, like so:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "ProductName": "2 Zits My Style",
    "Description": "2 zits | stof | Stof grof geweven lichtgrijs",
    "Price": "579.00",
    "Picture": "~/UserImages/8195299-254-02.jpg",
    "CatID": 5,
    "alternateproducts": {
                           [ 
                             {
                               "Id": 24,
                               "ProductName": "Zitbank Ravenia",
                               "Description": "2 zits | stof | Stof ribstof taupe",
                               "Price": "1.139.00",
                               "Picture": "~/UserImages/8192530-94-02.jpg",
                               "CatID": 5
                             },
                             {
                               "Id": 25,
                               "ProductName": " Zitbank Gino",
                               "Description": "2 zits | Stof velours okergeel",
                               "Price": "499.00",
                               "Picture": "~/UserImages/8194150-01.jpg",
                               "CatID": 5
                             } 
                           ]
                         }
  },
  {
    "Id": 4,
    "ProductName": "Slaapbank Hervik",
    "Description": "Cubos 50 lever",
    "Price": "1.499.00",
    "Picture": "~/UserImages/8202978-06.jpg",
    "CatID": 11
  }
```

Code is as follows:

```
       var structured;

       // Application
        app.route('/products')
        // GET endpoint
        .get(cors(), function(req, res) {
    
            // create Request object
            var request = new appmodule.sql.Request();
                
            // query to the database and get all the records
            request.query('SELECT * FROM Products', function (err, recordset) {
                
                if (err) console.log(err)
    
                GenerateStructuredJSON(recordset);
                res.json(structured);
            });

        });

        function GenerateStructuredJSON(recordset) {
            var products = recordset.recordset;
            structured = getNestedProducts(products);

            function getNestedProducts(prod) {
                for(var i = 0; i < prod.length; ++i) {
                    var productId = prod[i].Id;         
                    var alternativeproducts = getAlternativeProducts(productId);
                    console.log(alternativeproducts); // logging nothing but Promise { <pending> }
                    if(alternativeproducts) {
                        prod[i].alternateproducts = alternativeproducts;
                    }
                }
                return prod;
            }
        }

        async function getAlternativeProducts(prodID) {
            const rs = await new Promise(function(resolve, reject,) {
                var request = new appmodule.sql.Request();
                request.input('prodid', sql.Int , prodID);
                request.query('SELECT Products.* FROM Products ' +
                'RIGHT JOIN ProductAlternatives ON ProductAlternatives.AlternativeProductId=Products.Id ' +
                'WHERE ProductAlternatives.ProductId=@prodid', function(err, res) {
                    if (err) throw err
                    resolve(res.recordset);
                })
            });
            console.log(rs); // logging json product structures correctly
            return rs;
        }
```

The strange thing is that the resultset rs from the async function is logged correctly with console.log(rs);, but as soon as it is connected to the var alternativeproducts in function getNestedProducts, it is logging nothing but empty `Promise { <pending> }`'s. So the resultset seems to be lost or unavailable at that time.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that async function in node.js is just a Promise. The line

```
 var alternativeproducts = getAlternativeProducts(productId);
```

assigns the Promise to alternativeproducts.

You can make function GenerateStructuredJSON(recordset) async, then in your main function, you can then

```
 await GenerateStructuredJSON(recordset)
```

But then you will need to await on all Promises from getAlternativeProducts created for each product.

I think a better approach is to have one sql to include the alternative product as part of the result using LEFT OUT jOIN. Then you will just need to structured the resulting JSON to the expected format.

Also, after

```
if (err) console.log(err)
```

it should not continue, i.e:

```
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.json(err);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your assistance. I am relatively new to Express and I did not realize that async/await has to be implemented in order to get resultsets available and return them. I have made some adaptations to the code. The code is running without any problem now and is returning the product list including the alternative products as an array:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "ProductName": "2 Zits My Style",
    "Description": "2 zits | stof | Stof grof geweven lichtgrijs",
    "Price": "579.00",
    "Picture": "~/UserImages/8195299-254-02.jpg",
    "CatID": 5,
    "alternateproducts": [
      {
        "Id": 24,
        "ProductName": "Zitbank Ravenia",
        "Description": "2 zits | stof | Stof ribstof taupe",
        "Price": "1.139.00",
        "Picture": "~/UserImages/8192530-94-02.jpg",
        "CatID": 5
      },
      {
        "Id": 25,
        "ProductName": " Zitbank Gino",
        "Description": "2 zits | Stof velours okergeel",
        "Price": "499.00",
        "Picture": "~/UserImages/8194150-01.jpg",
        "CatID": 5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 4,
    "ProductName": "Slaapbank Hervik",
    "Description": "Cubos 50 lever",
    "Price": "1.499.00",
    "Picture": "~/UserImages/8202978-06.jpg",
    "CatID": 11
  },
  {
    "Id": 10,
    "ProductName": "Slaapbank Larvik",
    "Description": "Etnos 11 middengrijs/taupe",
    "Price": "1.299.00",
    "Picture": "~/UserImages/8201672-08.jpg",
    "CatID": 11
  },
```

But the code is relatively slow, it lasts 3 seconds to return data from 13 records. It might be an option to implement one JOIN query for all products and include the alternative products, and then use JSON AUTO for the json result.

Working code here:

```
        // Application
        app.route('/products')
        // GET endpoint
        .get(cors(), function(req, res) {
    
            // create Request object
            var request = new appmodule.sql.Request();
                
            // query to the database and get all the records
            request.query('SELECT * FROM Products', async function (err, recordset) {
                
                if (err) console.log(err)
    
                var outputstructure = await GenerateStructuredJSON(recordset); // wait for async function to return
                res.json(outputstructure); // send outputstructure to AJAX method in html document
            });

        });

        async function GenerateStructuredJSON(recordset) {
            var products = recordset.recordset;
            var structured = await getNestedProducts(products); // wait for getNestedProducts to return
            return structured; // return the prod array (structured = prod)

            async function getNestedProducts(prod) {
                for(var i = 0; i < prod.length; ++i) {
                    var productId = prod[i].Id;         
                    var alternativeproducts = await getAlternativeProducts(productId);
                    //console.log(alternativeproducts);
                    if (alternativeproducts != '') {
                        prod[i].alternateproducts = alternativeproducts;
                    }
                }
                return prod; // return full input array prod but with alternateproducts as additional attribute
            }
        }

        async function getAlternativeProducts(prodID) {
            const rs = await new Promise(function(resolve, reject,) {
                var request = new appmodule.sql.Request();
                request.input('prodid', sql.Int , prodID);
                request.query('SELECT Products.* FROM Products ' +
                'RIGHT JOIN ProductAlternatives ON ProductAlternatives.AlternativeProductId=Products.Id ' +
                'WHERE ProductAlternatives.ProductId=@prodid', function(err, res) {
                    if (err) throw err
                    resolve(res.recordset); // resolve sets rs to value of res.recordset
                })
            });
            //console.log(rs); // logging json product structures correctly
            return rs;
        }
```

Note that request.query and getNestedProducts(prod) are async now and getAlternativeProducts(productId) awaits the result from the async function.